# How to send to django template from dictionaries / tuples in a relational manner?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

So I have an alphabet dictionary which has the letter name as the key and an integer as an id for the value. (This is used for the jump to navigation at the top of the page which is hardcoded html)

Then I have many named tuples. Each one is for a state. It has the alphabet id state name and state id.

Then theres many named tuples for partners. Each has a state id, image url, link, and partner name.

The part which I am struggling with is how to display these in the template. I want each state to go in an alphabetical manner, to have a jumpto-nav id, and partners in that state.

Greatly appreciate any feedback!!!
Thanks.

Note: the dictionary/tuples are located in views.py

Answer (score 0):

You have a context dictionary that you send to the template from a view. Use the django.shortcuts.render function to return the context dictionary.
Suppose:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Write a view
def show_states(request):
    states = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
    return render(request, 'show_states.html', {'all_states' : states})
```

Then you can access them in the templates